# A question about intersection number on surfaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, intersection-theory

This question is from the Qing Liu's book: *Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves*, Exercise 9.1.6.

> Let $X\to S$ be an arithmetic surface and $X_s$ a closed fiber. Let
>   $C_1,...,C_m$ denote the connected components of $X_s$. Let $V\in\operatorname{Div}_s(X)$ be a vertical divisor with support in $X_s$. Show that the
>   following properties are equivalent:
>
> (i) $V\cdot D = 0$ for every $D\in\operatorname{Div}_s(X)$;
>
> (ii) $V^2 = 0$;
>
> (iii) $V\in\bigoplus_{1\le i\le m}\mathbb{Q}C_i$.

Comment: What is your question about this exercise?

Comment: I do not know how to use the condition (ii).

Comment: Well, obviously (i) => (ii).  Do you mean you're having trouble showing (ii) => (iii)?

Comment: Yes, that is my trouble.